# Who made commercialization of beer possible

Tags: history, specialty-beers, laws, local, recommendations

Who was the person or company that made beer selling commercial .

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably the dawn of human civilization.  Beer was probably one of the first consumables ever commercialized.  We can find commercial receipts for the sale of beer dating back over 4,000 years (Alulu beer receipt, 2050 BC) and advertisements for beer from even further back ([Ebla Tablets, 2500-2250 BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebla_tablets))

Hammurabi's Code from ~1750 BC has several sections detailing punishments for bartenders who try to short-change their customers.

Realistically, beer has probably been a commercial product for longer than it hasn't.

Comment: Adding on this, I am fairly certain that the oldest written recipe is of beer.